# Why does the same Prolog query produce duplicate results only in specific cases?

Tags: prolog

While working in Prolog I frequently encounter that my implementation produces duplicate results when querying specific things. Below is my knowledge base:

```
connection(bus,kerkrade, heerlen, 1100, 1200).
connection(bus,kerkrade, bleijerheide, 1100, 1125).
connection(plane, kerkrade, sittard, 1100, 2100).
connection(bus, bleijerheide, heerlen, 1200, 1215).
connection(bus,heerlen, kerkrade, 1115, 1230).
connection(bus,heerlen, maastricht, 1230, 1330).
connection(plane, heerlen, groningen, 1400, 1420).
connection(bus,maastricht, heerlen, 1430, 1530).
connection(plane,maastricht, sittard, 1415, 1430).
connection(bus,maastricht, sittard, 1345, 1445).
connection(train,maastricht,sittard,1345,1600).
connection(bus,sittard, maastricht, 1630, 1530).
connection(bus,sittard, denbosch, 1530, 1700).
connection(plane,sittard, groningen, 1520 ,1700).
connection(bus,denbosch, sittard, 1800, 1930).
connection(bus,denbosch, amsterdam, 1000, 1330).

validConnection(T,X,Y,Z, connection(B,X,Y,S,W)):-
    connection(B,X,Y,S,W),
    member(B,T),
    (Z =< S).

findRoute(TransportList,DepartureLoc,ArrivalLoc,TimeLeftAtHome,ToSolve):-
    route(TransportList,DepartureLoc,ArrivalLoc,TimeLeftAtHome,[],ToSolve).

route(T,A,B,Time,V,[Head|L]) :-
    validConnection(T,A,X,Time,Head),
    not(member(X,V)),
    (
        B = X, L=[];
        connection(_,A,X,_,S),
        route(T,X,B,S,[A|V],L)
    ).
```

Querying if there is a route between Heerlen and Sittard, I get the following non-duplicate result:

```
findRoute([bus,train,plane],heerlen,sittard,900,V)

V = [connection(bus, heerlen, maastricht, 1230, 1330), connection(plane,    maastricht, sittard, 1415, 1430)] ;
V = [connection(bus, heerlen, maastricht, 1230, 1330), connection(bus, maastricht, sittard, 1345, 1445)] ;
V = [connection(bus, heerlen, maastricht, 1230, 1330), connection(train, maastricht, sittard, 1345, 1600)] ;
false.
```

However, querying again, but this time our destination is groningen, I receive the following output in which every result is duplicated:

```
findRoute([bus,train,plane],heerlen,groningen,900,V)

V = [connection(bus, heerlen, maastricht, 1230, 1330), connection(plane, maastricht, sittard, 1415, 1430), connection(plane, sittard, groningen, 1520, 1700)] ;
V = [connection(bus, heerlen, maastricht, 1230, 1330), connection(plane, maastricht, sittard, 1415, 1430), connection(plane, sittard, groningen, 1520, 1700)] ;
V = [connection(bus, heerlen, maastricht, 1230, 1330), connection(bus, maastricht, sittard, 1345, 1445), connection(plane, sittard, groningen, 1520, 1700)] ;
V = [connection(bus, heerlen, maastricht, 1230, 1330), connection(bus, maastricht, sittard, 1345, 1445), connection(plane, sittard, groningen, 1520, 1700)] ;
V = [connection(bus, heerlen, maastricht, 1230, 1330), connection(train, maastricht, sittard, 1345, 1600), connection(plane, sittard, groningen, 1520, 1700)] ;
V = [connection(bus, heerlen, maastricht, 1230, 1330), connection(train, maastricht, sittard, 1345, 1600), connection(plane, sittard, groningen, 1520, 1700)] ;
V = [connection(plane, heerlen, groningen, 1400, 1420)] ;
false.
```

Using the built-in debugger I keep losing track of what is happening and can't see where the problem is. I have tried some minor edits to my KB but it keeps producing the same results. 
I am aware that I can use `setof\3` and others methods to negate the duplicate results, but that's not what I am interested in. I have also checked the facts to see if there are any duplicates in them and there aren't.

How is it possible that the second query produces duplicate results while the first one doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try cut (!) in various places in your program but it is not so easy. An easy way would be to write:

```
findall(V,findRoute([bus,train,plane],heerlen,groningen,900,V),L),sort(L,L1).
```

This will create a list of lists (L1) with all answers. To get only one answer (one list) and by pressing '`;`' get another...(of course with no duplicates) you could add:

```
member(L1,Result).
```

To answer to your question, the problem is in the lines:

```
 connection(_,A,X,_,S),
 route(T,X,B,S,[A|V],L)
```

There you want to say if there is a connection `then` find route...
but this should be using `->` (then operator):

```
 B = X, L=[];
 connection(_,A,X,_,S)->
 route(T,X,B,S,[A|V],L)
```

Example:

```
?- findRoute([bus,train,plane],heerlen,groningen,900,V).
V = [connection(bus, heerlen, maastricht, 1230, 1330), connection(plane, maastricht, sittard, 1415, 1430), connection(plane, sittard, groningen, 1520, 1700)] ;
V = [connection(bus, heerlen, maastricht, 1230, 1330), connection(bus, maastricht, sittard, 1345, 1445), connection(plane, sittard, groningen, 1520, 1700)] ;
V = [connection(bus, heerlen, maastricht, 1230, 1330), connection(train, maastricht, sittard, 1345, 1600), connection(plane, sittard, groningen, 1520, 1700)] ;
V = [connection(plane, heerlen, groningen, 1400, 1420)] ;
false.
```

This is exactly what the above sentence-goal should be written in Prolog-code . By using `,` (and) it is not the same and finds more cominations.

As a conclusion it is not easy to find such duplicates, (in more complicated programs it may be very hard) so using the above solution with findall or anything else that removes duplicates may be more easy.

Comment: It's a good answer! But you provide another method to surpress the problem instead of clarifying the symptoms. :-) Maybe I should have made that more clear in my question so I will edit it!

Comment: Excellent answer. Much appreciated! I'm happy you also kept your original answer and explained the contrast between the difficulty of finding the cause of such problems and the ease of using methods like `setof/3`